# Aurelia App file is too big

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia, filesize

I'm new to Aurelia so i need guides,I'm using Aurelia TypeScript Webpack, Facing an issue with the size of the App file when importing these below plugins :

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'jquery-datetimepicker';
import 'select2';
import 'bootpag/lib/jquery.bootpag.min';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
import 'bootstrap-notify';
```

The size became 8m it's too large for one file how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure it's 8M? What about the rest of the app? The best choice is dividing your app in several bundles.

Comment: I did that but there is a problem when i separate the plugins into chunks, if i did that they doesn't work but if I added them all on the app they are working fine ?

Comment: You can add them all but you should separate the rest of the application into chunks